# Does the metric kubernetes.pod.memory.usage also counts cache/buffer usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Trying to keep track of memory usage for a pod in k8s. Does the metric kubernetes.pod.memory.usage counts cached/buffer size? If yes, which metric should I use to keep track of actual memory usage

Answer (score 3):

1. Does the metric kubernetes.pod.memory.usage counts cached/buffer size? The answer is **Yes**.

[image]

2. Which metric should I use to keep track of actual memory usage? `container_memory_working_set_bytes`

[The article](https://faun.pub/how-much-is-too-much-the-linux-oomkiller-and-used-memory-d32186f29c9d) is recommended to you:

> You might think that memory utilization is easily tracked with `container_memory_usage_bytes`, however, this metric also includes cached (think filesystem cache) items that can be evicted under memory pressure.The better metric is `container_memory_working_set_bytes` as this is what the OOM killer is watching for.